# Why is my id null in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a very basic and default project, I'm attempting to add an edit view for applicationuser in the manage controller.  Here are my controller methods:

```
    // GET: /Manage/Edit/1 
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit()
    {

        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(user);
    }

    // POST: /Manage/Edit/5 
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Email,Id,FirstName,LastName,Phone,Company,Description,Website")] ApplicationUser formuser, string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        user.Email = formuser.Email;
        user.FirstName = formuser.FirstName;
        user.LastName = formuser.LastName;
        user.Phone = formuser.Phone;
        user.Company = formuser.Company;
        user.Description = formuser.Description;
        user.Website = formuser.Website;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Update the user details 
            await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            return RedirectToAction("Edit");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My view is using the applicationuser model, and I believe I've extended the applicationuser correctly(just added a few fields).  However, when I submit the form, I get a bad request with very little detail, but I assume my id is null and it's hitting the null check.  I have almost identical code working in another project and I can't for the life of me find any difference.

I think this is enough information, but I'm really not understanding what's happening here.

Comment: `but I assume my id is null ` - step 1. use the debugger + confirm your assumption.

Comment: So it seems you want the `id` to have a value, so are you sure you are passing the `id` parameter in the query string? We would need to see the calling code/html

Comment: in your view for your edit page.. what happens if you put `@Html.HiddenFor(model.ID)`?

Comment: Just checked, user is null.

Comment: @MVC_Future_Guru you need to post your markup and your model definition.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to accept both 'id' and 'Id' which one are you passing? Are you passing both? Look into that.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Awesome.  I missed that somehow - post it and I'll give you the checkmark.  It's still not saving, but at least my user is no longer null - was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Edit View, use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model.ID)
```

it might not be saving because you are initializing everything else that you're binding except for the id.

try

```
user.Id = formuser.Id;
```